# connection to localhost works but not ip

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

If I connect to the database using 'localhost' as hostname, It works

```
$flag = [
'database_host' => 'localhost',
'database_port' => '',
'database_name' => 'dbdemo',
'database_user' => 'userdemo',
'database_password' => 'uijk',
'database_table' => 'tabledemo',
];

$link = mysqli_connect($flag['database_host'],$flag['database_user'],$flag['database_password'],$flag['database_name']);
```

But when I set up the hostname by using his ip (which I get through `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];`), It returns the error

```
Connection refused
```

I'm confused, is it not basicaly the same thing?

Comment: Are localhost and the IP the same computer? If not, it's nothing like the same thing, and you need to make sure to use the right port, and the right credentials, and be allowed through the firewall, and not have exclusion rules in the config, etc. etc.

Comment: Does it work with `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Remember if you connect using `userdemo@192.168.0.22` for example. Then you have to have setup a user account in MySQL for this `user = userdemo` that is allowed to connect from a Domain of ? Whatever the ip address of your PC is.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok ok, it makes sense, I didn't knew that. So it's about permission. Btw it works with 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yes, you need to add an account for `userdemo` that is aloowed to connect from your Client PC's ip address

Comment: I think `127.0.0.1` is an alias for `localhost` -- neither are considered IP addresses.